# R ggplot2 geom_tile Several graphs in the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am working on the following tennis data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)

Year<-c(1999:2020)
Player <- rep("Federer",22)
Rank<- c("Q1","3R","3R","4R","4R","W","SF","W","W","SF","F","W","SF","SF","SF","SF","3R",
     "SF","W","W","4R","SF")
Fre<-c("1R","4R","QF","1R","1R","3R","SF","F","F","F","W","QF","F","SF","QF","4R","QF",  
       "A","A","A","SF","NH")
Wim<-c("1R","1R","QF","1R","W","W","W","W","W","F","W","QF","QF","W","2R","F","F","SF",
       "W","QF","F","NH")
US<-c("Q2","3R","4R","4R","4R","W","W","W","W","W","F","SF","SF","QF","4R","SF","F",
       "A","QF","4R","QF","NH")

data <- data.frame(Year, Player, Rank, Fre, Wim,US)
data$Rank <- factor(data$Rank, levels = c("3R","4R","Q1","SF","F","W"))
data$Wim <- factor(data$Wim, levels = c("NH","1R","QF","SF","F","W"))
data$Fre <- factor(data$Fre, levels = c("NH","A","1R","3R","4R","Q1","QF","SF","F","W"))
data$US <- factor(data$US, levels = c("NH","A","3R","4R","Q1","Q2","QF","SF","F","W"))
```

I want to visualize the categorical variables Wim, Fre and US as I did with Rank but in the same plot using geom_tile function.

The plot only with Rank variable looks like that:

[image]

The commands I used for the previous plot are:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=factor(Year),y=Player,fill=Rank)) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill=Rank),color="black", width=0.9,height=0.4) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("cornflowerblue","cyan2","aquamarine1","green",
"cyan4","yellow"))+
theme(axis.text.y  = element_text(color="black", size=8, face="bold"),
panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"))+
xlab("Years")+ylab("Tournament")+coord_flip()+  theme_bw()
```

What I want to do is to put three more diagrams in the same plot next to this with the rest three variables and the same colors for the levels plus some more colors for levels that don't appear in Rank variable.

I tried to add three more lines in my code as it seems below but it doesn't work.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=factor(Year),y=Player,fill=Rank)) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill=Rank),color="black", width=0.9,height=0.4) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill=Fre),color="black", width=0.9,height=0.4) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill=Wim),color="black", width=0.9,height=0.4) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill=US),color="black", width=0.9,height=0.4) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("cornflowerblue","cyan2","aquamarine1", 
"green","cyan4","yellow"))+
theme(axis.text.y  = element_text(color="black", size=8, 
face="bold"),
panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"))+
xlab("Years")+ylab("Tournament")+coord_flip()+  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to gather your data from its wide format to a longer version where instead of a column for each variable, you have one column that indicates which variable is referred to, and another the value for that variable. Then the grammar of graphics looks after it for you.

```
library(tidyr)

data_long <-   gather(data, variable, value, -Year, -Player)

ggplot(data_long, aes(y = factor(Year), x = variable, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", width = 0.9,height = 0.4)
```

You will need more colours of course for the different levels than you currently have.

I don't know what you intend to do with more players but you will probably want to use `+ facet_wrap(~Player) when you get their values - keeping everything in a long thing data frame of the same type as here.